# Register Jackson as a Message Body Reader for Media-Type "text/plain" with Jersey JAX-RS

Tags: java, jersey, jackson

I have an existing Jersey/JAX-RS annotated resource that has a method that `@Consumes("application/json")` which takes a JSON serialization of a POJO and deserializes it into the POJO. I need to for some legacy reasons also allow it to consume data when the Content-Type is "text/plain" where the HTTP body content will still be JSON.

Does anyone know how I can accomplish this? Right now, if I modify the @Consumes annotation to add "text/plain" Jersey throws an exception saying it doesn't have a suitable Message body reader for the "text/plain" MIME and my Java Type:

`A message body reader for Java class REDACTED, and Java type class REDACTED, and MIME media type text/plain was not found.`

Thanks!

Comment: Did you consider to provide your own messagage body reader implementation handling text/plain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up just re-writing the Content-Type as it comes in using a ContainerRequestFilter... I do not love this solution, but it works. Source is Groovy if it looks a bit funky to Java-folks.

```
final class TextPlainToApplicationJsonContentTypeRewriteFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    ContainerRequest filter(ContainerRequest request) {
        if(request.getHeaderValue(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE).trim().startsWith(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)) {
            request.requestHeaders.putSingle(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        }

        request
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This might be a more efficient way of handling this.

```
@Provider
@Consumes({ MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN })
public class FTMessageBodyReader extends JacksonJsonProvider {

    @Override
    protected boolean hasMatchingMediaType(MediaType mediaType) {
        return true;
    }

}

final Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
client.register(new LoggingFilter(Logger.getLogger("FTCLientFactory"), true));
client.register(FTMessageBodyReader.class);
```